# foreach loop with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

this mysql update:

```
 function updateOrder($id_array){
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($id_array as $id){
      $update = mysqli_query($this->connect,"UPDATE `table_name` SET `order_id` = $count WHERE id = $id");
      $count ++;  
    }
    return true;
  }
```

i'll change to PDO , this my write code but can work .
 but that is not reflected in the db

```
function update($id_array,$_table){

        $query = "UPDATE `table_name` SET `order_id` = ? WHERE id = ?";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);  

        $count = 1;
         foreach ($id_array as $id) { 
    $stmt->execute(array(':$count' =>  $count, ':id' => $id));
      $count ++;
        }
          return true;
      }
```

call funtion :

```
$idArray    = explode(",",$_POST['ids']);<br>
$db->update($idArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':count' =>  $count, ':id' => $id));
```

instead of

```
$stmt->execute(array(':$count' =>  $count, ':id' => $id));
```

**:$count** to **:count**

Comment: Did you pass the table in update($id_array,$_table)?

Comment: try like this global $conn;  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);